# SQL Server max timestamp per day for specific column from joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, gtfs, sql-timestamp

I'm really new to SQL and have essentially googled my way to this point, I'm pretty stuck now.. so I hope someone out there can help!

Goal: get the rows with the most recent timestamp per day for every trip_id in MS SQL Server (there are multiple tables that need to be joined to get the data needed).

So each trip_id should have 1 row per day, like so… [removed some columns for readability]

```
timestamp,trip_id,stop_id,stop_code,arrival_time,departure_delay
4/28/2017 18:29,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,0
4/27/2017 18:26,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,60
4/25/2017 18:27,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,-120
4/28/2017 18:56,8888922,2847,52818,11:32:34,-60
4/25/2017 18:59,8888922,2847,52818,11:32:34,120
4/28/2017 19:34,8888922,2847,52818,12:02:34,360
4/27/2017 19:31,8888922,2847,52818,12:02:34,540
4/25/2017 19:27,8888922,2847,52818,12:02:34,-120
```

However right now the best I've been able to  do is get the maximum timestamp for each day and departure_delay with the following query

```
select
max(trip_updates.timestamp) as max, stop_times.trip_id, stops.stop_id, stops.stop_code, stop_times.arrival_time, trips.service_id,
stops.stop_name, stop_times.shape_dist_traveled, stop_time_updates.departure_delay
from stops
inner join stop_times on stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id
inner join trips on trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id
inner join routes on trips.route_id = routes.route_id
inner join trip_updates on stop_times.trip_id = trip_updates.trip_id
inner join stop_time_updates on trip_updates.oid = stop_time_updates.trip_update_id
where
stop_code = '52818'
and service_id = '1'
and stop_times.arrival_time between '11:00%' and '14:00%'
and route_short_name = '134'
group by stop_times.trip_id, stops.stop_id, stops.stop_code, stop_times.arrival_time, trips.service_id,
stops.stop_name, stop_times.shape_dist_traveled, stop_time_updates.departure_delay
order by stop_times.arrival_time asc, max(trip_updates.timestamp) desc
```

Which is giving me results like...

```
timestamp,trip_id,stop_id,stop_code,arrival_time,departure_delay
4/28/2017 18:29,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,0
4/28/2017 18:21,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,30
4/28/2017 18:16,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,60
4/28/2017 18:11,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,120
4/27/2017 18:26,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,60
4/27/2017 18:22,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,30
4/27/2017 18:20,8888922,2847,52818,11:02:34,0
```

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You either need to select fewer columns (such that you don't have to group by each individual column), or use a ROW_NUMBER() method (partitioning by trip_id and ordering by your timestamp desc).

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but now I simply get row #'s for each row and every entry per day.

`select max(trip_updates.timestamp) as max, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by max(trip_updates.timestamp) order by stop_times.trip_id) as row, stops.stop_id,...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, one way to achieve this if you need to select all your current columns would be using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) window function and removing your `GROUP BY`. For example,

```
SELECT [Max] = [timestamp], trip_id, stop_id, stop_code, arrival_time, service_id, stop_name, shape_dist_traveled, departure_delay
FROM
(
    SELECT trip_updates.[timestamp], stop_times.trip_id, stops.stop_id, stops.stop_code, stop_times.arrival_time, 
           trips.service_id, stops.stop_name, stop_times.shape_dist_traveled, stop_time_updates.departure_delay,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stop_times.trip_id, CAST(trip_updates.[timestamp] AS DATE) ORDER BY trip_updates.[timestamp] DESC) 
           -- This assigns a row number for each row within each trip_id and each day, where a row number of 1 will be the highest timestamp.
    FROM ... 

    <put all your current joins / where clauses here>

    AND route_short_name = '134'
    -- Note: no GROUP BY
) AS T
WHERE RN = 1 -- This ensures you select only the the first row for each trip_id.
ORDER BY arrival_time, [timestamp];
```

Comment: I realized there is a flaw in the data that is going to force me instead to compare the timestamp (datetime) field to arrival_time (varchar). The timestamp field is UTC time and arrival_time is -07:00 utc. Could you please assist in modifying this so that instead of giving me the max timestamp it gives me the closest timestamp to arrival_time?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would probably be to change any time you're using arrival_time to `DATEADD(HOUR, 7, arrival_time)` or something like that (-7 on the timestamp column would also work, if you want to use local time instead of UTC time).

Answer (score 0):

You can join onto a subquery which has what you want:

```
SELECT  last_trip.timestamp AS max ,
        stop_times.trip_id ,
        stops.stop_id ,
        stops.stop_code ,
        stop_times.arrival_time ,
        trips.service_id ,
        stops.stop_name ,
        stop_times.shape_dist_traveled ,
        stop_time_updates.departure_delay
FROM    stops
        INNER JOIN stop_times ON stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id
        INNER JOIN trips ON trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id
        INNER JOIN routes ON trips.route_id = routes.route_id

        -- instead of joining directly to trip_updates, join to query
        -- that will number the entries per day
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT * ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY trip_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS rownum
                     FROM   trip_updates
                   ) AS last_trip ON stop_times.trip_id = last_trip.trip_id and rownum = 1 -- and join on the latest

        INNER JOIN stop_time_updates ON trip_updates.oid = stop_time_updates.trip_update_id
WHERE   stop_code = '52818'
        AND service_id = '1'
        AND stop_times.arrival_time BETWEEN '11:00%'
                                    AND     '14:00%'
        AND route_short_name = '134'
GROUP BY stop_times.trip_id ,
        stops.stop_id ,
        stops.stop_code ,
        stop_times.arrival_time ,
        trips.service_id ,
        stops.stop_name ,
        stop_times.shape_dist_traveled ,
        stop_time_updates.departure_delay
ORDER BY stop_times.arrival_time ASC ,
        MAX(trip_updates.timestamp) DESC;
```

Comment: This appears to have the same result as my query, I get max timestamp per day, but every departure_delay variant has its own row instead of giving me just the last timestamp for each day per trip_id

Comment: @BradT Ah, I missed a `and rownum = 1` on the subquery join. Sorry for that!